# Add project references in Xamarin's Shared Project

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin

I am using Xamarin to develop iOS and Android application.I have creates one shared project which is common for both platforms.
As I am using database its common and put in shared project.I need to encrypt database, so need to add native sqlite library reference in shared project so that I can modify that code.

My question is : I have not found any way to add reference of other project/library in shared project.

Is that bug or expected behavior?

Any explanations are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Also interesting is you can't create one by itself. I was hoping to use one for cross-application sharing. I think it's like a big wrapper to emulate unix like hard links ;)

Comment: Then how one can add library reference in shared project?.If not then whats the use of it??just to share common code ?

Comment: Your shared project has access to all references of project that is using your shared project... And yes Shared project is just advanced files linking, only difference is that you have to link to file once for all 3+ projects(Android, iOS, WP...) otherwise you would have to change each of this projects. Notice that you can pick current project of shared file in top left corner of file...

Answer (score 5):

There are no '**References**' from the usual sense of **adding a project reference** from a **Shared Project**.

There is definitely scope for a **Shared Project** to be opened up further than it currently is, however its not, and this is by design, currently, although limiting in some ways.

In short, **Shared Projects** have no generated outputs.  It is from other projects that reference the **Shared Project**(s) that compilable outputs are generated - based on any conditional compilation symbols that you may have specified.

In order for you to add **sqlite** library references you need to use **NuGet** in order to add packages to your solution.

These **NuGet** packages will then also install and create your platform specific library references appropriate for each platform you are targeting.

If you take a look on your platform specific projects, you will see the **References** *treeview node* expand when you add a **NuGet** package and install it into those projects with the library outputs appropriate for the package.

You can then code in the **Shared Project** against these **NuGet** packages that are referenced in your projects.

**Update 1:-**

If you've added the package from **NuGet**, most things should line-up perfectly in general unless there is any platform specific stuff included.

If there is functionality that is specific to a particular platform; **or** for a library that is *only added directly to a platform-specific project*, then you can use conditional **#if** statements in the **Shared Project** to access these platform-specific differences.

**Update 2:-**

Example:-

1) You have a **Shared Project** and **Android**, **iOS** and **WindowsPhone** platform-specific projects that reference this **Shared Project**.

2) Create another new **WindowsPhone** *Class Library Project*.

3) Add the following class to it:-

```
public class MyWindowsPhoneClass1
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

4) In your **WindowsPhone** *platform specific project*, add a **Reference** (in this case it will be a *Solution reference* as it is part of the same solution) to the new **WindowsPhone** *Class Library Project* you created in *Step 2*.

5) Enter the following code into some function in the **Shared Project**:-

```
PhoneClassLibrary1.MyWindowsPhoneClass1 o;
o = new PhoneClassLibrary1.MyWindowsPhoneClass1();
string strResponse = o.SayHello();
```

and compile.

You will notice you will get compilation errors for **iOS** and **Android**, as **PhoneClassLibrary1** could not be found.

**However....**

If you now change the code to:-

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
    PhoneClassLibrary1.MyWindowsPhoneClass1 o;
    o = new PhoneClassLibrary1.MyWindowsPhoneClass1();
    string strResponse = o.SayHello();
#endif
```

You will see that your project now compiles on **ALL 3 platforms due to the use of conditional #if statements**.

Comment: But how to access library in shared project which is referenced in platform specific projects.Without reference how can we code at common place ?

Comment: I knew about platform specific compilation, but can I use api's of those library without any reference in shared project?

Comment: I've updated my answer, See *Update 2*, with an example.  References are not added to the Shared Project as they can't be.

Comment: Means I have to add sqlite NuGet package reference in suppose android project, So am I able to access NuGet library API's in Shared Project by means of conditional compilation?

Comment: No - When you add the NuGet package you are then able to configure what platform-specific projects this be installed on by clicking some checkboxes only.  It will handle the file referencing and adding of files to each platform specific project for you.  So once you've installed the sqllite pakage, go to NuGet Manager again, find this package in the installed packages and click the 'Manage' button.  You will then be able to select the projects that it will be installed on.

Comment: As far I know only platform specific projects can have access to edit reference so nuget package can only be added in those project, not in solution nor in shared project.Just by adding package in android project how can one use its API outside in shared project upon configuration?

Comment: Can you send across your current project so I can see where you are?  My contact details are on my Profile.

Comment: I haven't heard back from you, so I am assuming your on your way to getting this to work ok?  In response to your last comment, just like what we did in *Update 2* with the conditional #if's you can do similar if you want to write Android specific code also in your Shared Project that is not executed on other platforms.  Please re-read over my entire answer as it will explain clearly that Shared Projects have no references, and how your able to use NuGet to control package installations into platform specific projects.  It also describes how you can write individual platform specific code also

Comment: Your answer is beyond the scope of the question. User asks only how to use the references their using on their platform specific projects.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of adding reference to Shared Project in Xamarin.

Shared Project is just a centralised project to shared codebase (like Model and ViewModel) between multiple projects (Android and iOS projects).

**Solution:**

Add the reference to the Android / iOS project and it will be automatically be accessible from the Shared Project.

Answer (score 0):

References and components are not supported by **Shared Projects**. So, if you have no platform-specific project, a **Shared Project** is of no use, as you won't be able to abstract any of the needed references and/or components for your applications.

A **Shared Project** depends on you referencing it on any other platform-specific project, so you'll be able to use all references and components this platform-specific project uses.

To reference the **Shared Project** on any platform-specific application, right click the **References** folder of that application and select *Edit References...*, select the tab *Projects* and check the box of your **Shared Project**. After that, you can use any reference of that application on you **Shared Project**.